# Extract content of div including tags with BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello when i do like below:

```
soup.find('div', id='id1')
```

I am getting like this :

```
<div id="id1">
<p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>
<span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>
<div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>
<h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>
</div>
```

Where as I need only like this :

```
<p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>
<span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>
<div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>
<h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>
```

Is there any way to get contents like above? I tried with .contents but not getting What I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div id="id1">
<p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>
<span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>
<div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>
<h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
el = soup.find('div', id='id1')
print el.decode_contents(formatter="html")
```

Outputs:

```
<p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>
<span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>
<div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>
<h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `contents` I got following:

```
[u'\n', <p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>, u'\n', <span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>, u'\n', <div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>, u'\n', <h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>, u'\n']
```

Iterating through list, You can easily get output You want (skipping `\n` elements).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming soup.find is the variable name, then:

```
soup.find = re.sub("<div>.*<\/div>", "", soup.find)
```

may work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific function in `BeautifulSoup` that would do exactly what you need - [`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap):

> `Tag.unwrap()` is the opposite of `wrap()`. It replaces a tag with whatever’s inside that tag. It’s good for stripping out markup

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div id="id1">
<p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>
<span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>
<div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>
<h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
soup.div.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

would print:

```
<p id="ptag"> hello this is "p" tag</p>
<span id="spantag"> hello this is "p" tag</span>
<div id="divtag"> hello this is "p" tag</div>
<h1 id="htag"> hello this is "p" tag</h1>
```